# The import liquibase.util.grammar cannot be resolved

Tags: grammar, javacc

I am trying to build the source code, I am upgrading form 3.5.3 to 3.6.2.
Using Eclipse, installed the JavaCC plugin. My grammar files are not being generated.

Per the Liquibase website %M2_HOME%/bin/mvn package to build.

I finally force compiled the SimpleSqlGrammar.jj file. It wouldn't compile automatically in its regular place in the file structure. I still have Java errors:

> LINE_COMMENT cannot be resolved or is not a field LINE_COMMENT cannot be resolved or is not a field MULTI_LINE_COMMENT cannot be resolved or is not a field WHITESPACE cannot be resolved or is not a field .

These errors I can only see in Eclipse.

When I build using Maven command line, then I still have Maven errors:

> ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.0.2:resources (default-resources) on project liquibase-core: Error loading property file 'D:\workspace\liquibase2\liquibase-parent\liquibase-core\target\filter.properties'

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: When you generated the parser, did you get a file called `SimpleSqlGrammarParserConstants` in the folder representing package `liquibase.util.grammar`?